# How to extend amount of VLAN's via external Managed Switch on Linksys WRT Router on OpenWRT 21

Tags: router, switch, vlan, openwrt

Goal is to create more than 4 VLAN's leveraging external ports on Managed Switch all under control of the Main Router (Linksys WRT with 4 built-in switch-ports) running OpenWRT 21.

Linksys Managed Switch with 8 switch-ports running Linksys web interface allowing easily assigning VLAN-ID to each individual switch-port.

Configuring 4 VLAN's works fine since the Main Router has 4 physical switch ports, but how to also get VLAN 5, 6, 7, ... via additional ports on Managed Switch.
There are 5 groups (and in future possible more) that all require their own VLAN.
1 = LAN
2 = GUEST
3 = SALES
4 = R&D
5 = STAFF

Router switch-port 4 connects to Switch switch-port 8 and is configured on both sides as a Trunk port (to transfer frames with VLAN-data back and forth). On both the Router and Switch, the switch-ports 1-3 are configured respectively with VLAN-ID 1-3.

Main router configuration via Luci web interface.

### Steps

1. On Router created new Bridge-device "br-lan" to bridge the 4 switch-ports of main router (Network -> Interfaces -> Devices)
2. On Router configured VLAN's on the "br-lan" device with ports 1-3 set to respective VLAN 1-3 and port 4 set as trunk port, see image.

[VLAN-configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE1YB.png)

3. On Router created 4 interfaces (LAN / GUEST / SALES / R&D)

- Each interface has DHCP-server configured (10.10.1.0 / 10.10.2.0 / 10.10.3.0 / 10.10.4.0)
- Each interface is linked to the respective "br-lan" device, being "br-lan.1", .., "br-lan.4"

4. On Switch for switch-port 1-7 a VLAN-ID is configured, respectively VLAN-ID 1-7. Switch switch-port 8 is configured as Trunk.

### Result

1. **Works:** Connecting laptop to Router switch-port 1-4 works, it provides IP in range as configured in each interface DHCP-server (10.10.1.0 for Router switch-port 1, 10.10.2.0 for Router switch-port 2 etc.)
2. **Works:** Connecting laptop to Switch switch-port 1-4 works, it provides IP in range as configured in each interface DHCP-server (10.10.1.0 for Switch switch-port 1, 10.10.2.0 for Switch switch-port 2 etc.)
3. **Fails:** On Router to add additional VLAN-5 for the group STAFF. It works to configure additional VLAN-ID 5 on the "br-lan" device. Then create an interface "STAFF" on the newly created device "br-lan.5" (Trunk port on Router connected to the Switch), enabling DHCP with 10.10.5.0/32.
   However, connecting the laptop to Switch switch-port 5 (configured with VLAN-ID 5) then no IP-address is assigned.

Something in this last step goes wrong, connecting the laptop to Switch switch-port 5 does not result in getting IP assigned 10.10.5.*.
What is missing here?

Many thanks for ideas and support.

[Adding VLAN-5 to "br-lan" device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEjW9.png)

[Adding Interface "STAFF" connected to newly created "br-lan.5"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baJmP.png)

Answer (score -1):

Change /32 to /24

/32 is only 1 address

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.